# 9 speed Shimano Deore derailleur compatibility

Tags: shimano, derailleur, derailleur-rear, freewheel

Will a 9 speed Shimano Deore derailleur be compatible with my 13-32 tooth freewheel?

Comment: Also browse through https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=m591 and see what's relevant/interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your RD-M591 is a 9 speed rear derailleur, and has these ratings:

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Low sprocket_Max | 34T |
| Low sprocket_Min | 28T |
| Capacity | 45T |
| High sprocket Max | 12T |
| High sprocket Min | 11T |

So nominally your high gears are not high enough, there's a reasonable chance it would work anyway.  It could be a bit noisier and have slower shifting in the high/hard gears.

Your low gear of 32 is between 28 and 34, and will work fine at that end.

Do note this particular derailleur does not have a clutch.  I'm not sure if there exists a 9 speed derailleur from Shimano with a clutch.

Comment: It must also be noted that Shimano is rather conservative concerning the MIN/MAX values. The system will not self-destruct for one or two teeth beyond the official values.

Comment: I was unable to find the model number but it does say L-TWOO A5 on the outside. I believe it is the cheapest derailleur on amazon but that isn't exactly my problem with it, my problem is that the tension it provides is so incredibly weak that if I were to take it off a curb it would slap. I would love a clutch but with my speed and tooth range that would be impossible. All I want from my derailleur is a relatively strong tension that will prevent 60% chain slap. Do you think the Deore would suit my needs?

Comment: @river I meant the model of the Deore derailleur you plan to buy, not the current one.

Comment: Oh, its RD-M591

Comment: @River Put simply, derailleurs like RD-M591 being bad at controlling chain slap is the whole reason for the move to clutch derailleurs. In its day the answer would have been run a super thick chainstay protector, and then a chain guide if needed. The situation is no different now. It sounds like it may be better than what you have but it is a pretty humble MTB derailleur.

Comment: @NathanKnutson agreed.   The only benefits from this new derailleur would be less-slop from wear, and maybe a stronger spring.